# Subtract table from another table in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 3 tables - `Users`, `Images` and `Users_Images`.
Each user can buy many images and each image can be bought by multiple users.
The fields of the tables are as below:

```
Users - Id, UserName, Password

Images - Id, Name, Description, Path
```

`Users_Images - UserId, ImageId, PurchaseDate`.
(All the relationships between the tables are set)
I'm trying to build a query that will select a table with all images that has not been bought by a specific user
my algorithm was to select a table with all image that a specific user has been bought and subtract it from the full table of image.
But no matter how I tried to write it as a query it always gave me wrong or not complete results.
Some of queries I tried:

```
SELECT Id, [Name], Description, Path 
FROM Images
EXCEPT
SELECT Id, [Name], Description, Path 
FROM Images AS I INNER JOIN Users_Images AS UI
ON I.Id = UI.ImageId
WHERE UserId = 1
```

OR

```
SELECT Id, [Name], Description, Path 
FROM Images
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
SELECT Id, [Name], Description, Path 
FROM Images AS I INNER JOIN Users_Images AS UI
ON I.Id = UI.ImageId
WHERE UserId = 1)
```

I also searched for solution here and other websites but none of them worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```
SELECT Id, [Name], Description, Path 
FROM Images as I
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Users_Images AS UI
                  WHERE UI.ImageId = I.Id AND
                        UI.UserId = 1
                 );
```

This simply returns all images that have no rows in `user_images` where the user id is 1.

Answer (score 0):

use `not in`

```
select im.Name,im.Description,im.Path from Images im where im.id not in (

select i.id Users_Images ui join Images i on ui.ImageId=i.id
join Users u on ui.UserId=u.Id
where u.UserId=1
)
```

Comment: your first query gives me a syntax error
and the second gives invalid error

Answer (score 0):

Your second version needs to be correlated :

```
SELECT im.*
FROM Images im
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Images AS I INNER JOIN 
                       Users_Images AS UI
                       ON I.Id = UI.ImageId
                  WHERE UI.UserId = 1 AND I.Id = im.Id
                 );
```